# AJAX: How to send back a success/error message

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

This is my first baby step with Ajax and I'm already struggling. I have a request that inserts into the DB but my code for the moment is behaving like all the requests are successful, but I want to be able to handle the errors when updating the DB. I want to alert() a success/error message depending on the MYSQL response.

My Ajax call:

```
$("a.bgbtb").click(function(){
  var btnid = $(this).attr("id").split('newbudbtn-')[1]; 
  var newbudget = $("INPUT[id=newbud-"+btnid+"]").val(); 
  var platform = $("span#"+btnid).text(); 
  $.ajax({
    url:"campbdgtedit.php", 
    method:"POST",  
    data:{platform:platform, btnid:btnid, newbudget:newbudget},  
    success:function(data){
        myAlertTop();
    }
  });
});
```

campbdgtedit.php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO campaigns (camp_budget, camp_campaignid) VALUES ('".$_POST['newbudget']."', '".$_POST['btnid']."')";

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Success<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

How can I catch if there is an error in the query and handle my alerts accordingly? I've tried many solutions I've found here but I can't seem to make them work.

Comment: This is a really good question and it's great you're thinking about how to handle errors appropriately. What database extension are you using; MySQLi, PDO, etc?

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could link in those other solutions you checked out and attempt to explain how they haven't worked for you. It will help narrow down where your problems are stemming from.

Comment: The DB I use is MySQLi and the solutions I've checked, even though, I tried to make them work for my case they have a different objective and a different code that I was just copy/pasting hoping that it might work, but I had no understanding of how things work and I was doomed to fail.

Comment: `success:function(data){
        console.log(data)
    } ` **data** is the returned information from the php/db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend returning `JSON` from your PHP code, this can be interpreted directly as an object in the JavaScript if you use `dataType: 'json'` on your ajax call. For example:

```
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 
                           'message' => "Error: Insert query failed"
                           )
                     );
}
```

Note that in general it's not secure to pass back query details and connection errors to the end user, better to pass back a generic message and log the actual error to a file or other location.

In your JavaScript:

```
$("a.bgbtb").click(function(){
  var btnid = $(this).attr("id").split('newbudbtn-')[1]; 
  var newbudget = $("INPUT[id=newbud-"+btnid+"]").val(); 
  var platform = $("span#"+btnid).text(); 
  $.ajax({
    url:"campbdgtedit.php", 
    method:"POST",  
    data:{platform:platform, btnid:btnid, newbudget:newbudget},  
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        if (data.success) {
            // all good!
            myAlertTop();
        }
        else {
            // problems
            alert(data.message);
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please don't expose `$conn->error` to the end user.

Comment: @Dharman to be fair, I just copied OPs code but you raise a good point. I've changed it and made a note about security.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For those that want to use the code above they have to parse the jquery before accessing the message. jQuery.parseJSON(data).message

Comment: @CreekBarbara as long as you use `dataType: 'json'` returned `JSON` should get automatically parsed into the `data` variable (so it will be an object)

Comment: @CreekBarbara from the [manual](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): "If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler."

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you need to analyze the "echo" from the php side in the JS side in order to alert the appropriate error.

Use the "data" that is returned here:

```
 success:function(data){
        myAlertTop();
    }
```

and do the following:

```
 success:function(data){
        myAlertTop(data);
    }

function myAlertTop(replyfromPHPside)
 {
  if (replyfromPHPside =="abc")
   {
    alert('..');
   }
  else
   {
    ...
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. myAlertTop(); is the function I fire if the MYSQLi response is a success, if not it should fire another function. The "abc" is the echo from campbdgtedit.php?

Comment: that's the entire goal. the: myAlertTop should handle both success and both failure. on php side? => if you have a success, echo "success" and check it on myAlertTop. So if it is a success, it will call one function, otherwise, will call or do whatever you want. It should handle all the states (pass / failure)

Comment: No myAlertTop is the response for a success only. It's the overlay display with a success message,

Comment: ajax:success will succeeds even if the mysql query failed. It is referring to the ajax's call and not to whatever happened inside the php file, so you need to analyze yourself, based on the echos from the php file :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to echo out a json-string from PHP and "catch" the response in javascript like this:

**campbdgtedit.php:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO campaigns (camp_budget, camp_campaignid) VALUES ('".$_POST['newbudget']."', '".$_POST['btnid']."')";

$arr = array();
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    $arr['response'] = true;
} else {
    $arr['response'] = false;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.bgbtb").click(function(){
  var btnid = $(this).attr("id").split('newbudbtn-')[1]; 
  var newbudget = $("INPUT[id=newbud-"+btnid+"]").val(); 
  var platform = $("span#"+btnid).text(); 
  $.ajax({
    url:"campbdgtedit.php", 
    method:"POST",  
    data:{platform:platform, btnid:btnid, newbudget:newbudget},  
    success:function(data){
        if (data.response == 'true') {
            alert('DB success');
        }
        else {
            alert('DB fail');
        }
    }
  });
});
```